# Create bibliography in latex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I want to create this bibliography in latex, but it doest not work and I just get  ?. How can I solve this problem?

```
      \begin{filecontents*}{bibtest.bib}
        @book{goossens93,
        author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
        title = "The Latex Companion",
        year = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
      }
      \end{filecontents*}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{natbib}

   \begin{document}

   \cite{goossens93}

   \bibliographystyle{chicago}
   \bibliography{bibtest}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

? appear in the output file after the first latex run.  Then you need to run bibtex (which uses the .aux file from the first latex run). Re-run latex twice more. If latex can not find the .bib file an error will appear in the log. Same if the .bib file does not contain a cited item.